# Benchmarking functions multiple times - All calls after first are instruction cached?

Tags: c, benchmarking, cpu-cache

I'm writing a small benchmarking library in C which is used to benchmark single functions. The way it works is that you supply the benchmarking function with a pointer to a `void` function without parameters and the number iterations. The function then returns a `struct` with information about

However when looking at the individual results I see that the first call takes up a lot of time and then the calls after takes up very little time.

So I'm wondering:

1. Is this due to instruction caching?
2. If yes to first question, how does benchmarking tools generally conform to this? Is the first call excluded?
3. If yes to first question, is there a case when caching is not applied to a function?
4. If yes to first question, does caching occur on whole functions or segments of a function?
5. If yes to first question, is there anything else I should consider that I should read up on and understand better?

---

### Data and code

The function which retrieves the time:

```
double currentTime()
{
    struct timeval time;
    struct timezone timezone;
    gettimeofday(&time, &timezone);
    return time.tv_sec + time.tv_usec * 1e-6;
}
```

Test result:

```
0.000319
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000001
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
Total time: 0.000320
Average time: 0.000032
Worst time: 0.000319
Best time: 0.000000
```

Result without optimizing flag:

```
13.425430
13.349757
13.482863
13.129472
13.020705
13.672982
13.027595
13.139602
13.028962
13.107892
Total time: 132.385260
Average time: 13.238526
Worst time: 13.672982
Best time: 13.020705
```

The function being tested which produces this result:

```
void test()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i++ < UINT_MAX){}
}
```

Make file:

```
CC = gcc
MAIN = main.c
SOURCES = lib/tb_time_handling.c lib/tb_rendering.c tb_benching.c
OUTPUT = main
FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -O2

all: main

main: 
    $(CC) $(MAIN) $(SOURCES) -o $(OUTPUT) $(FLAGS)
```

Github repo with all code:

https://github.com/Ancide/TinyBench

**Edit: Forgot to mention compiler and compiler flags**

**Edit 2: Added git repo with all code in case someone wants to see everything**

**Edit 3: Added results withouth O2 flag**

Comment: Interesting! Without the O2 flag the results are much more uniform and a lot higher. I guess the compiler can tell the CPU to cache instructions when it's optimizing.

Comment: I would take a closer look at the -O2's output, chances are the compiler is taking out the loop anyway, as it's not really doing anything productive. Does it really make a loop, or just "i = UINT_MAX" ?

Comment: @Nico That sounds really reasonable! I didn't even think of that. But why would the first call be so much slower?

Comment: @Nico Looking at the assembly of the function we see that what you suggest seems to be correct. Without O2: http://codepad.org/mXXKAMwy and with O2: http://codepad.org/ZM1LOW1w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal in virtual memory operating systems.  The first call to a function tends to generate a page fault which loads the code from the executable file into RAM.  If you are interested in actual code perf then you ignore the first call.  If you are interested in realistic perf measurements then you don't ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is this general or is there some cases when this doesn't happen? Will it happen if I don't supply the O2 flag?

Comment: It has nothing to do with optimization.  Paging is page based, 4096 bytes at a time.  So sometimes the code is already loaded by accident.

Comment: Alright. Any reading tips to get a better picture? This is way over my head atm.

Comment: Hard to give tips if we don't even know what operating system you use.  Any text about modern operating system design ought to suffice.

Comment: I see! It's unix-based. But I guess some googling on my side of paging and memory-management will take me far!